# Adding comments to xib file

Tags: objective-c, comments, xib

I am working on xib file that has many objects, which hide each other and also change in code.

I would to make my work, and any other future programmer easier by adding comments in the xib file.

I thought of just putting some text area outside the view I'm using, but I want to make sure I'm not effecting the final executable.

Is this a valid way to do it?

Comment: No. Instead create the UI from code and comment the code.

Comment: If you have a lot of stuff in your xib already, don't think adding any comments would help because of limited screen space.

Comment: H2COM3- creating the UI from code is much more confusing. Had experience with that

Comment: theAmateurProgrammer - I would usually agree, but since the part of the UI I'm using does not show on xib, as it would on run, I'm afraid it would be confusing, and I rather have it documented than leaving the programer puzzled

Answer (score 3):

1./ In interface-builder, select the object to comment, open the inspector:
in the last tab (with the (i) icon, at the bottom of the inspector panel, you'll see a note area: write your comments there. You may want to click on "show with the selection".
2./ comment in code any object that should change programmatically

Comment: Great answer, and would be helpful for me in other cases. But in this specific case, the UI are hardly visible on xib, and I want to put something that would be catching the programmer eye.